# ActiveRecord query question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a rails 3 application.

I have the following scenario: There are students and teachers who have interactions. Based on some of these interactions, a teacher may elect to give a student a reward, i.e. a student_reward.

```
class Student
has_many :interactions
has_many :teachers, :through=>:interaction

class Teacher
has_many :interactions
has_many :students, :through=>:interaction
has_many :rewards

class Interaction
belongs_to :teacher
belongs_to :student
has_many :student_rewards
has_many :rewards, :through=>:student_reward

class Reward
belongs_to :teacher
has_many :student_rewards

class StudentRewards
belongs_to :reward
belongs_to :interaction
```

[image: This is a crude ERD diagramof the data]

How would an expert code an efficient approach to fetching all of the rewards that a student's teachers have [not necessarily ones that the student has won] and also list info on the teachers in the display?

I tried this, but I have to separately get the teacher information in the view, and this is bad. (assuming the student_id=1):

```
@rewards = Reward.joins(:teacher => :interactions)
                 .where("interactions.student_id=1")
                 .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```

Questions:

1. Is this the best way to do it?
2. When I am iterating through this in the view, I have to issue additional queries to display information about the teacher [name, deomographics]. How can I fetch this more efficiently?

I want to be able to do this:

```
<% for reward in @rewards%>
  <%= reward.name, reward.teacher.name, reward.teacher.bio%><br>
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the student, then getting the rewards for the student's teacher is easily obtained like so:

```
@student = Student.find(1)
@rewards = []
@rewards += @student.teachers.collect {|teacher| teacher.rewards }
```

The relationship you set in Student `has_many :teachers, :through=>:interaction` makes this possible.